# Javascript innerHTML before and after editing a value

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, window.open

i'm trying to query the source code of an opened window, after i alter a value.
At first i opened a new window and printed the source code of it.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        a=window.open("pageOnSameDomain.html");
        a.onload = function() {
            //To test it, i used 'alert' 
            alert(a.document.documentElement.innerHTML);

            //Old value of this field was 'hello'
            a.document.forms[0].inputField.value="aloha";

            //Again used 'alert' to test. But the value is the same as before
            alert(a.document.documentElement.innerHTML);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Now my problem is, that the output of the first innerHTML is the same as the output of the second innerHTML function.
But if i try to query exactly the value of the element, i get the correct value.

```
//Here it's 'aloha'
alert(a.document.forms[0].inputField.value);
```

Best regards

Comment: Setting a property doesn't have an effect to `innerHTML`, set attributes instead, if you want see changes in `innerHTML`.

Comment: It's entirely possible that by the time `a.onload  = ... ` is processed, the new window's `load` event may have already fired, in which case, your `onload` function will have missed its chance to be triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects (and therefore, the properties of those objects as well) are stored in memory. The `.innerHTML` is not a reflection of the DOM object in memory, to the contrary, it is the HTML code that has been parsed and used as the **initial** DOM object in memory. Changing a property does not change the `.innerHTML`.

`a.document.forms[0].inputField.value="aloha";` sets the `value` ***property*** of the field, it's doesn't cause a `value` ***attribute*** to be added to the element, so the `.innerHTML` remains unchanged, while the DOM in memory has been changed.

To change the HTML, you need to use:

```
a.document.forms[0].inputField.setAttribute("value", "aloha");
```